# KafkaStream stateStore stale data after rebalancing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We use Kafka streams to handle incoming GPS positions. 
The requirement is the following: If no position is received from a certain driver for x number of minutes, mark that driver as unavailable. 
With each new position, we populate the state store with driverId as key and actual position as value.
So far, so good. Then we want to introduce the scheduler to check the state store and mark each driver with a position older than x minutes as unavailable.

We are using Processor API for creating our topology.

```
StoreBuilder currentTrackabilityStateStore = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
                    Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("driver-trackability-store"),
                    Serdes.String(),
                    driverTrackabilityStateSerde());

Topology topology = new Topology()
            .addSource(partitionedDriverGpsSourceName,
                    Serdes.String().deserializer(),
                    Serdes.ByteArray().deserializer(),
                    MessageTopic.DRIVER_GPS_INTERNAL.getValue())
            .addProcessor(processorNameRequestId,
                    ProcessorRequestId::new,
                    partitionedDriverGpsSourceName)
            .addProcessor(deserializeProcessorName,
                    ProcessorDeserialize::new,
                    processorNameRequestId)
            .addProcessor(trackabilityProcessorName,
                    ()-> new ProcessorTrackability(trackabilityChangesSinkName),
                    deserializeProcessorName)
            .addSink(trackabilityChangesSinkName,
                    MessageTopic.TRACKABILITY.getValue(),
                    Serdes.String().serializer(),
                    driverTrackabilityStateSerde().serializer(),
                    trackabilityProcessorName)
            .addStateStore(currentTrackabilityStateStore, trackabilityProcessorName);
```

Init scheduler

```
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.kvStore = (KeyValueStore<String, GpsInfo>) context.getStateStore("driver-trackability-store");
        schedule = this.context.schedule(Duration.of(45, ChronoUnit.SECONDS), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, new GpsTrackabilityPunctuator(this.kvStore, this.context, trackabilityChangesSink));
}
```

Process method

```
   public void process(String key, GpsInfo gpsInfo) {
       // omitted
       this.kvStore.put(key, gpsInfo);
      // omitted
   }
```

Finally, there is puncturator

```
 public void punctuate(long timestamp) {
    log.info("Punctuating...");
    KeyValueIterator<String, GpsInfo> iterator = this.kvStore.all(); // Problem is right here
}
```

The problem is in this.kvStore.all() which apparently keeps stale information after rebalancing.
For example, a driver with id 10 will be assigned to partition which is being processed on instance 1, and the store will be populated with y records, then rebalance occurs and a driver 10 is now being processed on instance 2. The state is successfully migrated to instance 2, so when the schedule runs on instance 2, we will have all previous positions as well as new that are incoming. The problem is the scheduler is still running on instance 1. What happens then is no new positions are being saved and the scheduler is marking driver 10 as unavailable, while scheduler on instance 2 is marking the same driver as available because it has the latest position.
So is there a way to purge stale records from the state store after rebalancing? 
Am I missing something?

EDIT 1:

State store is backed up on startup from changelog topic. This is done for each task. Each task gets all messages from the changelog(regardless of partitions). This is why kvStore.all() returns all records, not just ones that are being processed by current task.

Comment: You can use `Processor#close()` to cancel all schedules when a rebalance occurs (note that `context.schedule(...)` returns a corresponding handler).

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake on my part. After many hours of debugging i have come to the conclusion that the issue was related to the source topic having records with key and without key.

It was somehow messing with the store rebalance mechanism.

The solution was to delete the source topic and create a new one that contained only records with keys.